# Breaking/Continuing nested for loops in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

How can I break/continue nested loops in Coffeescript? E.g. I have something like:

```
for cat in categories
  for job in jobs
    if condition
      do(this)
      ## Iterate to the next cat in the first loop
```

Also, is there a way to wrap the whole second loop as a conditional to another function within the first loop? E.g.

```
for cat in categories
  if conditionTerm == job for job in jobs
    do(this)
    ## Iterate to the next cat in the first loop
  do(that) ## Execute upon eliminating all possibilities in the second for loop,
           ## but don't if the 'if conditionTerm' was met
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`break` works just like js:

```cs
for cat in categories
  for job in jobs
    if condition
      do this
      break ## Iterate to the next cat in the first loop
```

Your second case is not very clear, but I assume you want this:

```cs
for cat in categories
    for job in jobs
      do this
      condition = job is 'something'
    do that unless condition
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, didn't know about break. However, putting the conditional in the if statement would not work because 'job' gets defined in the following line 'job in jobs', correct?

Answer (score 20):

Use [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). Since CoffeeScript doesn't support them, you need to hack as such:

```
0 && dummy
`CAT: //`
for cat in categories
  for job in jobs
    if conditionTerm == job
      do this
      `continue CAT` ## Iterate to the next cat in the first loop
  do that ## Execute upon eliminating all possibilities in the second for loop,
          ## but don't if the 'if conditionTerm' was met
```

Comment: (not supported by CoffeeScriptRedux)

Comment: @AndreyM No. You can think of the label as essentially naming the loop. When you break using a label, you aren't _going to_ to the labelled line - you're breaking out of the loop with the specified name. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you! You'd think CoffeeScript would allow something like a `::` to tell the compiler you mean an explicit label, and not an object literal. E.g., `topLoop:: for i in names` to desugar to `topLoop: for(var i = 0; …)`. Backticks won't always be possible, as [some projects blacklist them](https://github.com/atom/settings-view/pull/786#issuecomment-219277194).

Comment: Also, this won't work if CoffeeScript inserts an intermediate assignment between the loop and the hack. For instance, `\`NAME: //\` ⮒ for key, value of @hash` compiles to `NAME: //; ⮒ ref = this.hash; ⮒ for(key in ref){`, which obviously isn't going to work (⮒ represents line-breaks in the example code). A workaround is to supply the intermediate reference yourself: `ref = @hash; \`NAME: //\` ⮒ for key, value of ref`

Comment: (Edit: Thanks @Alhadis, your hack works!)
This doesn't work in the new CoffeeScript? It pollutes it by placing variables right before it...

`CAT: //;⮒
var  len, r, ref;⮒
      for (j = 0, len = ...`

Answer (score 10):

Coffescript's "break" only breaks the immediate loop and has no way of identifying an outer loop for breakage (annoying!). This following hack works in some instances for breaking out of multiple loops when a condition is met:

```
ar1 = [1,2,3,4]
ar2 = [5,6,7,8]

for num1 in ar1
  for num2 in ar2
    console.log num1 + ' : ' + num2
    if num2 == 6
      breakLoop1 = true; break 
  break if breakLoop1

# Will print:
# 1 : 5
# 1 : 6
```

Comment: JavaScript does in fact support breaking out of outer loops using [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), but in order to do this in CoffeeScript you would need the hack described in @matyr's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Using anonymous loop with return

```
do ->
  for a in A
    for b in B 
      for c in C
        for d in D
          for e in E
            for f in F
              for g in G
                for h in H
                  for i in I
                    #DO SOMETHING
                    if (condition)
                      return true
```

Comment: That's impressive and even looks pretty, but I'm not sure what it adds to the accepted top answer.

Comment: This really is the way to solve this case correctly in CoffeeScript - organize your code into a sub-function so that the function `return` breaks the outer-most loop you need to break - otherwise you are creating spaghetti code anyway. This must also be the design reasoning for not having labels in CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Coffeescript would never have multiple breaking/continuing statements, you have to stick to ugly and excessive flags polluting your code or try to replace it by `do` with a lambda and use `return` as a multiple break.

https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/4254

Answer (score 0):

For checking all elements in an array, maybe lodash's `every` would be of use?

https://lodash.com/docs#every

```
for cat in categories
  if _.every jobs, conditionTerm
...
```

Answer (score -22):

I suppose the design of your code is not very good if you want to use inner break/continue.
It seems to me that any programming language doesn`t allow that.

Using labels as someone suggested is also considered as bad style.

Comment: That's not really a fair statement unless you provide a refactored example that proves your point

Comment: well, 
1) labels are never good. they create spaghetti-style code
2) since double break is not available, one can always use inner conditions as it is described in answer by Mark Parson above.

Comment: This is a dogmatic claim based on semantics. Not everything called "label" is the same.

Comment: two level breaks are simple and elegant.

Comment: Please consider adding code to provide a reason for your claim. Just saying "not good" doesn't provide useful feedback.

Comment: I'd disagree about labels being *never* good; they have their place. *Very* limited legitimate uses, but they exist.

Comment: @VladyslavGoloshchapov You didn't actually answer the question. Insulting the OP and attacking other answers isn't considered an answer (unless you're a politician, of course). Please consider removing this answer or revising it to be more helpful, and doing your reputation a favor in the process.